# Why the data downloading is much slower than the uploading on GPU by using OpenCL?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl, gpu

I'm a beginner of OpenCL for image processing, I use Win7+VS2010+OpenCL2.0+OpenCV247.
The platform in my PC is intel i7 CPU + NvidIA GTX760.

Here is my work:

1. I used opencv to read image(1920*1080) from video, then copy image data and get the data pointer.

   ```
   uchar* input_data=(uchar*)(gray_image->imageData);
   ```
2. Then I want do some convolution and other image processing works on GPU, so I used OpenCL to upload this data(input_data) to the device memory(cl_input_data) which has been created before. The uploading step takes about **0.2ms**, it is fast.

   ```
   clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, cl_input_data, 1,
       0, ROI_size*sizeof(cl_uchar), (void*)input_data, 0, 0, NULL);
   ```
3. The main processing works on several kernels, and each of them takes less than 0.1ms which are all quite normal.

   ```
   clEnqueueNDRangeKernel( queue,kernel_box,2,NULL,global_work_size,local_work_size, 0,NULL, NULL);
   ```
4. After all the processing, I want to download the GPU memory(cl_output_data) to host(output_data), and this step it takes over **5.5ms**! Which is nearly 27 times slower than the data uploading step!

   ```
   clEnqueueReadBuffer( queue,cl_output_data,CL_TRUE,0,ROI_size * sizeof(char),(void*) output_data,0, NULL, NULL );
   ```

So, I'm just wondering, since I used the same device and the data size was exactly the same, why the uploading and downloading data's time is so different?

Oh, by the way, the time testing tool I used is something like QueryPerformanceFrequency(&m_Frequency);

Thank you!

Comment: The short answer is that GPUs are designed assuming that data goes from the rest of the computer, to the GPU, then to the display. While it's obviously *possible* to get data back from the GPU to the rest of the computer, it's not how it's really designed to work, so it's a lot slower.

Comment: Thanks for answering!!! So you mean it isn't an abnormal situation, right? However, I remembered the bandwidth of upload and download is almost the same. It is also puzzled for me...

Comment: Offhand, I don't remember exact numbers, so I'm not sure it's exactly normal, but as a general idea: yes, it's normal that reading back from the GPU is quite a bit slower than writing to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I remember, `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` is asynchronous call. It will return control without synchronization with device. So, when you measure time of `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`, it is just a time of launch, not of processing. `clEnqueueReadBuffer` forces device synchronization and waits until all previous kernel call will finish. Thus, your **5.5 ms** includes kernels execution time.

Comment: wow~! Thanks a lot! That should be the problem! And as the kernel execution time and data downloading time is mixed together how can I detect the time one by one?

Comment: @DavidDing can you try clFinish (), then start your timer, then download the buffer?

Comment: @DavidDing you can also use OpenCL events.